# Prism for Xamarin.Forms NavigationService OnNavigatedFrom/OnNavigatedTo

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

we are trying to use OnNavigatedFrom and OnNavigatedTo but the "OnNavigatedTo" is not called when needed

ViewModelOne:

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("ViewModelPageTwo", useModalNavigation: false);
```

ViewModelTwo:

```
var parameters = new NavigationParameters()
            {
                {
                    "Pesquisa",
                    TextoPesquisa
                },
                {
                    "DataEnvioInicial",
                    DataEnvioInicio
                },
                {
                    "DataEnvioFim",
                    DataEnvioFim
                },
                {
                    "DataHistoricoInicio",
                    DataHistoricoInicio
                },
                {
                    "DataHistoricoFim",
                    DataHistoricoFim
                },
                {
                    "TodasAsCaixas",
                    PesquisaEmTodasCaixas
                }
            };

            _navigationService.GoBackAsync(parameters);
```

The problem is that ViewModelOne -> OnNavigatedTo not trigger when GoBackAsync from ViewModelTwo

Comment: A lot more information is need in order to help you narrow down your issue.  First what version of Prism for Xamarin.Forms are you using.  What version of Xamarin.Forms are you using.  What is the structure of your current navigation stack?  What type of page is the previous Page?  When are you calling GoBackAsync? Please provide more details.

Comment: @BrianLagunas Xamarin.Forms: 2.3.1.114 | Prism: 6.2.0. The structure is: MasterDetailPage that is the MainPage, inside an NavigationPage with TabbedPage, inside a TabbedPage we have ViewModelOne as a child that is making _navigationService.NavigateAsync("PageTwo", useModalNavigation: false)... when the PageTwo GoBackAsync the method OnNavigatedTo in ViewModelOne is not fired.

Comment: So you are navigating away from a Page inside a TabbedPage to PageTwo, which is inside a nvigationPage?  That's a very interesting and confusing page hierarchy.  I'm not sure I have a clear understanding, but try placing the INavigationAware on the TabbedPageViewModel and see if it hits there.

Comment: Yes, when GoBackAsync hits my TabbedPage... i thought that when i make  _navigationService.NavigateAsync("ViewModelPageTwo", useModalNavigation: false); i was in the same navigation... there are a way to hits my ViewModelOne? Thanks @BrianLagunas

Answer (score 1):

So what's happening is when you call GoBackAsync, you are actually going back to the TabbedPage, not the actual Tab. For now, you can implement INavigationAware on the actual TabbedPage, and then pass your parameters to the selected Tab's VM in the code-behind.  Not optimal, but it will work for now.  There is actually a discussion on the GitHub site talking about the various issues when dealing with TabbedPages and it's children during navigation.  YOu can follow it here:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/650

Comment: Ok, i will wait for some news about that, for now i will do the "workaround" that you said, thank you for the fast and great help